# Validate multiple variables using CAT, GREP and IF

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to write a simple script that validates whether or not multiple variables exist in a file.

The idea is that if the `$var1` exists, continue to `$var2`. That part is easy, what I'm stuck at is the notion of making it continue even if $var1 isn't there. I'm passing that to another* .txt*.

I have `$var1` to `$var6`. Each one represents a word, either the word exists or not it should alert. And, if the word exists, it should do another task.

This is what I have right now:

```
if cat feed.txt | grep "$var1\|$var2\|$var3\|$var4\|$var5\|$var6" > list
```

This worked fine, but now I need to independently validate them. So I did this

```
if cat feed.txt | grep "$var1" > list
then
cat feed.txt | grep $var2 >> list
```

This worked too. But if $var1 isn't there, $var2 is overlooked. And I have 6 variables.

I've been looking at forums where `IF, ELIF, ELSE; THEN` operands are explain, but I'm struggling with the logic of all this.

Comment: no need for cat. Maybe `if grep -q "$var1" file ; then something ; fi ; if grep -q "$var2" ; then something_diff ; fi ; if ..etc ...` seems to fulfill your stated needs. You can always add a `exit` inside the `if ... ; fi` to stop altogether. Else post a more detail example of your needs. (If this is for production processing, you may want an `awk` script that can do it all in one process). Good luck.

Comment: What does it mean that _a variable exists in a file_? What is the syntax of a file? How do you recognize that a certain string is a variable? Could it be that you simply want to know, whether a certain set of **words** are present in a text file?

Comment: @user1934428 yes, sorry. That's what I wanted to say. There are words in the text file that I make as variables in the beginning of the script. Sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: Then it is is still not clear what you want to test: Whether **all words** occurs in the file, or whether **at least one word** occurs in the file? BTW, all this information should be put into the question, and not into a comment.

Comment: I understand, sorry I'm just learning how Stack works.
The idea is to know if any of the words exists. After that, those words should go to another part of the script to do other things, but I'll try that by myself.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checks are independent, use a loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
vars=( "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" ) # etc etc for additional vars...

for var in "${vars[@]}" ; do
  if grep "$var" feed.txt >> list ; then
    # found this variable - do something about it
    echo "Found $var"
  else
    # did not find this variable - do something else
    echo "Did not find $var"
  fi 
done
```

Comment: I've tried to run this but it doesn't find the variables. This is the code 
`
#!/usr/bin/env bash

vars=( "$var1 word1" "$var2 word2" "$var3 word3" ) # etc etc for additional vars...

for var in "${vars[@]}" ; do
  if grep "$var" feed.txt >> list ; then
    # found this variable - do something about it
    echo "Found $var"
  else
    # did not find this variable - do something else
    echo "Did not find $var"
  fi 
done
`
And the output
`
Did not find  word1
Did not find  word2
Did not find  word3
`
However, those words are in the file. I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the `"$var1 word1"` part of your comment - based on your error output I believe that's causing you to search for `<space>word1` (note the leading space) when `var1` is unset. Do you want to use variables or hardcoded strings?

Comment: Yes, so the variables are hardcoded. The words I'm looking for do not change, what changes is the feeds.txt. 
I suspect that hardcoded strings are the ones I'm supposed to use. Am I supposed to be using something like `declare`?

Comment: I've got it. I removed the variables, 'cuz they don't change, and it worked. The code wasn't looking for variables it was looking for strings. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Build the grep motif with variable contents:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -u

# Init variables here or in another file
var1=x
#var2=''
var3=y
var4=z
#var5='t'

declare -a var_names=(var1 var2 var3 var4 var5)

declare input_filename="$1"

declare grep_pattern=
declare var_name=
declare var_value=
for var_name in "${var_names[@]}"; do
    var_value="${!var_name:-}"
    # printf "var_name='%s' = '%s'\n" "$var_name" "$var_value"
    if [[ -n "$var_value" ]]; then
        [[ -n "$grep_pattern" ]] && grep_pattern+="|"
        grep_pattern+="$var_value"
    fi
done

# printf "grep_pattern='%s'\n" "$grep_pattern"

grep -E "$grep_pattern" "$input_filename"
```

Note:

- Pattern is like `x|y|z` and option `-E` option is used with `grep` command.

If you cannot use `-E` option, remove it and change pattern build from

```bash
        [[ -n "$grep_pattern" ]] && grep_pattern+="|"
```

to:

```bash
        [[ -n "$grep_pattern" ]] && grep_pattern+="\\|"
```

Other solution with multiple `-e` grep option:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -u

# Init variables here or in another file
var1=x
#var2=''
var3=y
var4=z
#var5='t'

declare -a var_names=(var1 var2 var3 var4 var5)

declare input_filename="$1"

declare -a grep_options=()
declare var_name=
declare var_value=
for var_name in "${var_names[@]}"; do
    var_value="${!var_name:-}"
    # printf "var_name='%s' = '%s'\n" "$var_name" "$var_value"
    if [[ -n "$var_value" ]]; then
        grep_options+=("-e")
        grep_options+=("$var_value")
    fi
done

# printf "grep_options='%s'\n" "${grep_options[*]}"

grep "${grep_options[@]}" "$input_filename"
```

This build method is useful when you use grep after pipe commands like `cat`, `awk` and whatelse and mandatory when you use and command like `tail -f ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=1
var3=""
var5=5

i=1
set -- "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4" "$var5" "$var6"
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    var="$1"
    # skip this $var if empty
    [ -z "${var}" ] && { 
            echo "var${i} is empty; skip it!"; 
            i=$((i+1))
            shift 1
            continue; 
        }

    # do something with varValue ${var}
    echo "var${i} value: ${var}"
    #grep "${var}" feed.txt > list
    
    i=$((i+1))
    shift 1
done

var1 value: 1
var2 is empty; skip it!
var3 is empty; skip it!
var4 is empty; skip it!
var5 value: 5
var6 is empty; skip it!
```